# New job with short project

Tags: new-job, job-security

I joined a new job in December (outsourced work). The job is nice enough; close to home, newish technology, okay-ish team etc.

One of my colleagues (quite a bit my senior) was discussing with me how the client decided to extend our contract. Apparently which was up-till March. Turns out that my manager (the one who has been working on this project) required 2 more resources till March and I got hired for it(I had other offers). The other person had just paused their other project.

Now I am currently on this job and I don't know how long this extension is suppose to last. Not to mention, I don't know if I will be even told if my contract (client side) is expiring. My contact mentions that I cannot be removed w/o a 3 month notice (add the fact that the company tends to keep people on the bench for 4-5 months), I have ample time, but I am not exactly willing to sit on the bench for an extended period.

There is always the chance I'll be moved to a different project, but my expertise is in Qt something not used extensively here. I am just wondering if I should ask my manager regarding the same.

P.S. My manager took my interview, so he could have always told me about the short contract.

Comment: FWIW I'm not totally sure what the question is here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *My manager took my interview, so he could have always told me about the short contract.*

Correct. There is a reason why it was not disclosed , most likely, you are not to be bothered about the stint of the current project.

While I do not disagree that you should have been given a fair heads up, however, this sounds very unlikely that a new hire was hired only for a 3-month requirement. It may be possible that either

- they have possibility for further extension of the current project, maybe in reduced scope. You are the new hire, to learn the work (while your senior colleague mentoring and guiding you) and once you're up to the speed, you'll be the one handling the work and the other member will return to the original project.
- they have other work / projects lined up, (based on your skill and expertise) after the current one is delivered.

As of now, I do not see anything to get worried. However, you can have a word with your manager regarding the road-map for the current project which should give you the idea about the status.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can find the opportunity for the same and try to find a non-confrontational way to ask it.